# Cakephp & mutliple CSS designs in one controller

Tags: cakephp, routes, themes

I'm running Cake 2 and the site is setup like:

```
/internal/company1
/internal/company2
/internal/company3
```

All of the above use the pages controller and I use routing to add pages after those urls.
e.g.

```
Router::connect('/company1/tests', array('controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'index'));
```

I'm not using themes. The problem I've run into is say for example I want a totally different CSS layout (theme I guess?) for company1/minisite (header and all)

What's the best way to achieve this? Themes?

Comment: Have you looked into layouts? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts

Comment: Thanks Nick - it was the paths that had me confused.

Answer (score 0):

According to the argument passed into your controller's method, you can change your layout using the following syntax:

```
$this->layout = 'layout1';
```

Create your different layouts with different css. Hope it will work for you.